# Shared instance of a view by multiple same viewmodels

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm implementing a WPF application with MVVM design pattern.
The idea is to have different representations of multiple data in a workspace.
One entity per workspace (which is a tab, actually) that can be seen in a detailed or summarized view.

For that, I used those articles :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx
http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/

Everything works quite fine, but when I instanciate 2 or 3 tabs with a summarized view for one given viewmodel, there is only one view instanciated.
So, If I input some text in a textbox, every textbox in every tab is modified.
I don't want that since one tab could be another entity in the list.

Switch between views is handled that way:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CusomterDetailTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
    <vw:CustomerDetailView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerListTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
    <vw:CustomerListView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CustomerListTemplate}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding View}" Value="Detail">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CustomerDetailTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

That's not what I want. Every tab should be independant.
I guess I'm missing something, but I cannot see what yet.

That's why I'm requesting your help.

Thank you.

Comment: The MVVM methodology uses one view model to one view. If you stick to that principle, you'll run into far fewer problems.

Comment: It seems everything is bound to the same viewmodel and so all of the controls are bound to the same data. Maybe consider using a collection of CustomerViewModel one for each tab

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand by "using a collection of CustomerViewModel"... Could you please elaborate ? Thanks.